# how to detect sharepoint crawlers in custom httpmodule

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, c#-3.0, httpmodule

I have written a custom http module which I successfully deployed to sharepoint. The purpose behind this module was to track if the users to the sharepoint site had accepted an EULA (represented as a cookie in the request context) and then simply redirect them to another website (running independantly) to accept our EULA etc. The problem that I am facing at the moment, is that while users with their web-browsers using the site are fine, everything works as it should, but the trouble occurs with things like the SPFarms serch failing etc when trying to index the site. My quesiton is basically, how/what should I be filtering to ensure that my module only executes my logic for a request coming from a webbrowser and how to detect any of sharepoints crawlers etc such as the search service etc? I realize i can hardcode it to check for the username that the service is running on and check the filepath extensions and filter on that, but that seems like horrible design. please advise if you know of a better way to do this please

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering based on the User-Agent string, in `Request.UserAgent` -- just don't rely on User-Agent for security purposes, since it can be faked.